# Running Multiple Access Points Per Available Adapter

Tags: python-3.x, uwp, windows-runtime

This python code only tethers the last access point on the loop. My goal is to run them altogether on my Windows machine so that I will see all the access points (from helloworldz0 to helloworldz{n}) on the available WiFi connections, since Windows normally supports creating multiple access points

```
from asyncio import CancelledError
from winsdk.windows.networking.connectivity import NetworkInformation
from winsdk.windows.networking.networkoperators import NetworkOperatorTetheringAccessPointConfiguration, NetworkOperatorTetheringManager

conn, connlist = NetworkInformation.get_connection_profiles(), []
for i, c in enumerate(conn):
    adap = c.network_adapter.network_adapter_id
    if adap in connlist:
        continue
    else:
        connlist.append(adap)
    netw, conf = NetworkOperatorTetheringManager.create_from_connection_profile(c), NetworkOperatorTetheringAccessPointConfiguration()
    conf.ssid, conf.passphrase = f'helloworldz{i}', f'helloworldz{i}'
    netw.configure_access_point_async(conf)
    try:
        resu = netw.start_tethering_async()
    except CancelledError:
        pass
```

I will be happy for your help!! :)